# How to limit Google Drive's client bandwidth usage?

Tags: google-drive, bandwidth

Is there any way to limit the amount of traffic Google Drive uses? I'm syncing Drive's content, and it almost swallows the entire bandwidth. I can't use Internet during sync operation.

Comment: You can pause syncing, and you can limit the folders that get synced, but I do not see any way to limit bandwidth. (Something Dropbox can do.)

Comment: I guess there should be a workaround for this. Maybe another application that be installed to control the bandwidth of other installed applications.

Comment: If you use QOS you could give it a lower priority.  However setup can be complex.

Answer (score 5):

There is a bandwidth setting in Advanced tab, where you can limit download and/or upload bandwidth.

[image: screenshot]

Make sure you are using the latest version.