# Is there a way to limit the bandwidth that Google Drive File Stream uses?

Tags: macos, internet, bandwidth, google-drive-file-stream

Is there a way to limit the bandwidth that Google Drive File Stream uses?

I'm using a Mac and when I resume syncing, the Internet becomes unusable. I have to stop syncing to browse simple web pages!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Drive File Stream has been updated with a graphical options menu since 2018, changing the upload and download bandwidth limits using `defaults` is no longer necessary. I'm leaving my original post here, but note that using `defaults` improperly can break your application settings at best and probably break your computer at worst.

However, if you know what you're doing, changing your Google Drive settings using the command line might be a neat parlor trick to show your friends.

---

## *** THE FOLLOWING IS NO LONGER RELEVANT ***

### Please use the regular options menu - it exists now.

I am guessing you are using Drive File Stream instead of the now-depreciated Google Drive application. For Drive File Stream, there currently is no graphical options menu. However, [this page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7644837?hl=en) from Google outlines how settings can still be changed using the `defaults` shell command.

In order to limit download bandwidth to 100 Kilobytes/second, open Terminal and enter the following command:

```
defaults write com.google.drivefs.settings BandwidthRxKBPS -int 100
```

The 100 can be changed to any integer value you choose, and note that the value is in kiloBYTES and not kiloBITS.

To set the value for upload speed, use the following command:

```
defaults write com.google.drivefs.settings BandwidthTxKBPS -int 100
```

In order to change all settings back to their default, you can use this command:

```
defaults delete com.google.drivefs.settings
```

Hope this helps! Comment with any questions you have.

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar option:

1. Right-click on File Stream.
2. Go to the Settings icon → Preferences → Network Settings.
3. The app will ask you to restart the service.

[image: Network Settins]

Answer (score -2):

There is a bandwidth limit setting in the Google Drive app's preferences (settings) -> Advanced.

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/869029/918567).

Comment: Thanks but I don’t have the settings or preferences option for google drive on my Mac. The answer you mentioned is for windows.

Comment: @useR There are such options for Mac.. [as stated in here](https://venturebeat.com/2015/01/14/google-drive-for-pc-and-mac-gets-option-to-limit-bandwidth-new-menu-with-upload-status-and-easier-sharing/). The feature is for both Windows **and** Mac. [Here is where to find it](https://support.oc.edu/hc/en-us/articles/203896055-Google-Drive-Desktop-Application-Selective-Syncing-Mac).

Comment: This is incorrect. The answer is for Google Drive not Drive File Stream.