# Is there a way to limit the bandwidth that Google Drive File Stream uses in Windows?

Tags: windows, internet, bandwidth, google-drive-file-stream

Is there a way to limit the bandwidth that Google Drive File Stream uses?

I'm using Windows 10 and when I resume syncing, the Internet becomes unusable. I have to stop syncing to browse simple web pages!

There is [official guide](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7644837) for editing registry, but I don't think these works. It still uses most bandwidth. 
 There is also [similar question here](https://superuser.com/questions/1346754/is-there-a-way-to-limit-the-bandwidth-that-google-drive-file-stream-uses), but for mac instead.